# How to implement AVAudioPlayer Inside Singleton Method?

Tags: ios, swift, singleton, swift2, avaudioplayer

**This is my code :**

```
class SomeAudioManager: NSObject
{

    class var sharedInstance: SomeAudioManager{
        struct Static {
            static var onceToken: dispatch_once_t = 0
            static var instance: SomeAudioManager? = nil
        }
        dispatch_once(&Static.onceToken) {
            Static.instance = SomeAudioManager()
        }
        return Static.instance!
    }
    func audioView(songname: NSString,format: NSString)
    {
        let audioPlayer:ava
        audioPlayer=try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(songname, ofType:format)!), fileTypeHint: AVFileTypeMPEGLayer3)
        audioPlayer!.delegate=self;
        self.audioPlayer!.play()
    }
}
```

That AVAudioPlayer is under NSObject but I can't implement it.

While typing let audioPlayer:AVAudio -> it didn't display anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not that it makes much sense but this compiles for me:

```
import AVFoundation
class SomeAudioManager: NSObject, AVAudioPlayerDelegate
{
    class var sharedInstance: SomeAudioManager {
        struct Static {
            static var onceToken: dispatch_once_t = 0
            static var instance: SomeAudioManager? = nil
        }
        dispatch_once(&Static.onceToken) {
            Static.instance = SomeAudioManager()
        }
        return Static.instance!
    }
    func audioView(songname: String,format: String) {
        let audioPlayer: AVAudioPlayer

        do {
            audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(songname, ofType:format)!), fileTypeHint: AVFileTypeMPEGLayer3)
            audioPlayer.delegate = self;
            audioPlayer.play()
        } catch {
            // error
        }
    }
}
```

So you need to import the framework, try-catch in swift are do-try-catch. Some other syntax fails are fixed as well.

The singleton is not used this way in Swift BTW.

**Usage:**

```
class someOtherClass {
    func doSomething() {
        SomeAudioManager().audioView("name_here", format: "format_here")
        SomeAudioManager.sharedInstance.audioView("name_here", format: "format_here")
    }
}
```

Comment: how to access this method in other class please add that to ,it will help for me

Comment: Edited to add the usage example. The first line is using a new instance and the second is using the shared instance.

Comment: Note that audio player probably gets deallocated just after it is created and nothing happens though. You should assign it somewhere in the class.

Comment: 2015-12-23 19:07:48.980 Ss[2549:153426] 19:07:48.980 WARNING:  40: ERROR: couldn't get default input device, ID = 0, err = 0!
2015-12-23 19:07:48.981 S[2549:153426] 19:07:48.981 WARNING:  40: ERROR: couldn't get default output device, ID = 0, err = 0!
2015-12-23 19:07:48.981 S[2549:153426] 19:07:48.981 ERROR:    708: Error finding valid input or output devices!
2015-12-23 19:07:48.982 S[2549:153426] 19:07:48.982 ERROR:    312: error -66680

Comment: Works for me. I even played a song with it on my device. Maybe you are using a simulator and the player is not supported? Or there might be some other part of the application which produces this error.

Comment: but if i use local declaration of avaudioplayer its work fine ,but when i am using it in singleton object i am getting error

Comment: The singleton in your case makes no sense. Explain what you are trying to achieve with it and I can advise you on what to do..

Comment: i am trying to play an audio at two view controller ,so i tooks if i make it as singleton method ,i can avoid merging of song

Comment: So what should happen instead of merging? Restart the play or simply break the operation? What happens if the first one is already done playing?

Answer (score 2):

As for the singleton part in you case (from comments) you should probable use something like this:

```
class MyAudioPlayer: NSObject, AVAudioPlayerDelegate {
    private static let sharedPlayer: MyAudioPlayer = {
        return MyAudioPlayer()
    }()

    private var container = [String : AVAudioPlayer]()

    static func playFile(name: String, type: String) {
        var player: AVAudioPlayer?
        let key = name+type
        for (file, thePlayer) in sharedPlayer.container {
            if file == key {
                player = thePlayer
                break
            }
        }
        if player == nil, let resource = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(name, ofType:type) {
            do {
                player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: resource), fileTypeHint: AVFileTypeMPEGLayer3)
            } catch {
                // error
            }
        }
        if let thePlayer = player {
            if thePlayer.playing {
                // already playing
            } else {
                thePlayer.delegate = sharedPlayer
                sharedPlayer.container[key] = thePlayer
                thePlayer.play()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the usage is:

```
MyAudioPlayer.playFile("Breach", type: "mp3")
```

Comment: thank you so much @Matic Oblak ,and advance merry christmas :)