# Swift - How to pause a playing audio by clicking the same button?

Tags: ios, swift, audio, pause

So I have a list of audio files and when a cell is pressed it plays the audio. This works fine but I am not able to pause it by clicking the same cell again.

My code for the table view:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
{
    let a = indexPath.section;
    let b = indexPath.row;

    var path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(musicArray[b], ofType: "mp3")
    var error:NSError?

    do{
        audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path!))
    }
    catch
    {
        print("Something bad happened")
    }

    if (audioPlayer.playing)
    {
        audioPlayer.pause();
    }
    else
    {
        audioPlayer.play();
    }
}
```

musicArray has the titles of the audio files

Comment: I think the problem is you always create audioPlayer each time of didSelectRowAtIndexPath. So the audioPlayer is the new, it does not your playing audio player and the state is always not playing. You should create a static audioPlayer or save audioPlayer to an array for fix it.

Answer (score 1):

You're creating a new `AVAudioPlayer` every time you select the cell. You need to keep a reference to the previous one and tell *that* audio player to pause.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a singleton object.

```
import AVFoundation
class SomeAudioManager: NSObject, AVAudioPlayerDelegate
{
    class var sharedInstance: SomeAudioManager {
        struct Static {
            static var onceToken: dispatch_once_t = 0
            static var instance: SomeAudioManager? = nil
        }
        dispatch_once(&Static.onceToken) {
            Static.instance = SomeAudioManager()
        }
        return Static.instance!
    }
    func audioView(songname: String,format: String) {
        let audioPlayer: AVAudioPlayer

        do {
            audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(songname, ofType:format)!), fileTypeHint: AVFileTypeMPEGLayer3)
            audioPlayer.delegate = self;
            audioPlayer.play()
        } catch {
            // error
        }
    }
}
```

It will be alive through the whole app.

[How to implement AVAudioPlayer Inside Singleton Method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34435387/how-to-implement-avaudioplayer-inside-singleton-method)

You can just create a singleton of the player so that you will always know if it's playing or not.